# dropping packets that contain string linux kernel module

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-module, netfilter

I'm trying to drop network packets that contain a string: i.e. if a webpage says "free download" on it i need my kernel module to drop the packets that contain that string. I'm trying to scan through sk_buff in the netfilter hook, but not sure if this is the right place to look for the string. here is the code:

```
unsigned int hook_func_outgoing(void *priv,
                struct sk_buff *skb,
                const struct nf_hook_state *state) {
    int pos;
    struct ts_config *conf;
    struct ts_state statetext;
    const char *pattern = "free download";

    conf = textsearch_prepare("kmp", pattern, strlen(pattern),
                             GFP_KERNEL, TS_AUTOLOAD);

    pos = textsearch_find_continuous(conf, &statetext, skb->data, skb->len);
    printk(KERN_INFO "pos: %d", pos); 
    printk(KERN_INFO "data: %s ", skb->data); 
    if (pos != UINT_MAX){
            return NF_DROP; 
        printk(KERN_INFO "found spam\n");
    }
    textsearch_destroy(conf);
    return NF_ACCEPT; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not as easy as it sounds.

I'm not fully aware of writing kernel modules for network filtering, so I cannot comment on your code. But I think the major problem here is that you have only access to the "raw" packet.
The internet nowadays is mostly encrypted using TLS (https) and thus you cannot read the content of the transfer on that level (which is good). This means that your module can only work on unencrypted HTTP-Connections. Another issue might be HTTP compression like [GZIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression) which can scramble your data too.